# Kendo Grid, how to handle error while fetching data from server

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

How to handle exception from Rest service "testReportReadUrl" in grid, Currently Grid displaying no records and not showing exception message.

```
<kendo:dataSource pageSize="20" serverPaging="true"
            serverSorting="true" serverFiltering="true" serverGrouping="true">
            <kendo:dataSource-transport>
                <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="${testReportReadUrl}"
                    type="POST" contentType="application/json" />
            </kendo:dataSource-transport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add error ="errorHandler" with data source as below

```
<kendo:dataSource pageSize="20" serverPaging="true" 
            serverSorting="true" serverFiltering="true" serverGrouping="true" error="handleError">
            <kendo:dataSource-transport>
                <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="${testReportReadUrl}"
                    type="POST" contentType="application/json" />
            </kendo:dataSource-transport>
```

And provide handler method

```
function handleError(e){
alert("An error occurred")

}
```